Smarty warning for participant_status when someone is registering for the waitlist
Drupal 10.3.1
CiviCRM 5.75.1
PHP 8.2
Smarty 4
When someone registers for the waitlist, the email contains the following two warnings:
Warning: Undefined array key "participant_status" in /home/mysite/www/www/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_resource_recompiled.php(52) : eval()'d code on line 95

Warning: Attempt to read property "value" on null in /home/mysite/www/www/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty4/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_resource_recompiled.php(52) : eval()'d code on line 95

I've tried commenting out the define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH'....) but it doesn't make a difference. I get the same results on PHP 8.1 and 8.2.
The only non-standard extension that affects events is CiviDiscount.
Not sure what else to try?

My guess is the problem is in Event/BAO/Event.php where it's not getting assigned. A quicky fix might be to add the following at line 1189: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/9bb515bc272bf1d04360b6d243c988a86cbf4e58/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php#L1189
// make sure the array key exists
$tplParams['participant_status'] ??= NULL;

Does that fix it?

Yes that fixed it! Thanks for the tip, much appreciated
